# Greek in Latex malfunctioning, again

Tags: pdftex, greek

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1,T2A,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,english,german,french,dutch,italian,spanish,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{polutonikogreek}Βίβλος Συντίπα τοῦ φιλοσόφου\end{otherlanguage}.

\end{document}
```

I suddenly get an error:

`Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ^^\ (U+001C) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.`

It was working two years ago.

`\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` not an option since I need Cyrillic very much.

Comment: works okay for me. Try ``\catcode`^^1c=13 \def^^1c{HEREHEREHERE}``  to find out where the problematic char is.